# How can I prevent the brower's painting of an img from being visible?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image, event-handling

When I add new images to the DOM, sometimes I can see the image being painted from top to bottom. Is there an easy javascript technique or an event handler I can use to make the full image appear only after the browser is done painting/rendering it?

Comment: Look into pre-loading your images as the site loads this would help to reduce what you are seeing.
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_preload.asp
On a side note check your network speed as a slow connection will mean it takes longer for the image to render.

Comment: I don't think this answers my question. My network speed is fine, as I am running this on a localhost. The issue is after the image starts loading, I can visibly see it render from top to bottom.

Comment: It might not be an issue now while your on localhost but if you publish your site or use the throttle tool in the development tab you will see the images take longer to render. 
you won't ever fully remove the render time but you can reduce it, pre-loading, reducing image file size are just a couple of ways I'm bringing to your attention that will help reduce it. :)

Comment: No matter how fast your network is, it still takes time to load an image, but once an image has been loaded once, a cached version is used for all subsequent requests, so you can pre-load in such a way that it is drawn in invisibly before attempting to use it. I'll let someone else provide an answer on that, I more wanted to add a comment to mention that you could also consider using progressive JPEGs instead of optimized JPEGs (assuming you can use JPEG...), which loads in quality passes rather than top to bottom. Not quite what you asked for, but In some cases this could be good enough!

Comment: could be multiple factors, hard to tell with out seeing it happen.

Comment: Thank you for all the great ideas! I hadn't heard of progressive JPEGs before, but that seems like a great optimization

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use JavaScript to hide the image until it is fully loaded.

HTML:

```
<img id="image" src="...">
```

JavaScript:

```
var image = document.querySelector('#image');

image.style.opacity = '0'; //set opacity to 0 (fully transparent)

image.onload = function(){ //when image is loaded, execute function
    image.style.opacity = '1'; //set opacity to 1 (fully visible)
}
```

---

Because I use opacity property in this example, you could even animate the image appearing.

CSS:

```
#image {
    transition: opacity .5s;
}
```